# Changes not showing up in NodeJs/ReactJs apllication running on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have made changes to some css and js file in my Node-React apllication which is deployed on Heroku. But the changes are not showing up when I git add . the project on heroku. ALthough the changes are not coming up when I run the project locally.

Any help would be appreciated on what could be the possible cause on the changes not getting deployed?

Comment: Try to run `git commit` and `git push`

Comment: I used them as well but changes don't show up. Running the app locally also does not show the changes I make to the js and css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a few more commands in your deployment workflow.

The `git add .` command is putting your **local** changes into **staging**.
You also need to run `git commit -m 'your commit message'` in order to commit those **local** changes to your **local** git repository.
Next, you need to run `git push` to push your **local** repository to the *remote* repository it is linked with.

Effective use of git is one of the most useful things you can teach yourself as a developer. It will enable you to contribute effectively to a team when the time comes. Here's a good starter article: [Basic Git With Examples](https://rubygarage.org/blog/most-basic-git-commands-with-examples).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have used all these commands to push the code to heroku. But still the changes are not showing up.

Comment: Even if I npm start the project (on localhost:3000), the changes I make to the project are not showing up on the local server.

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the file? Are you using a framework or anything? What tools are you building with?